# SELinux: allow Zend webapp to read/write to tree outside htdocs

Tags: selinux

I have a Zend web application running on a CentOS server with SELinux running in permissive mode (i.e. access-control decisions are recorded in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` but not enforced).  The application allows people to upload files, which are saved in a directory structure outside `htdocs` (e.g. `/var/acme/myapp/files`).  The application needs to write and delete files in that directory, as well as create, modify, and delete directories under that directory.

FWIW, httpd starts as `root`, then spawns processes as a separate user named `apache`.

I'd like to put SELinux into enforcing mode, but still narrowly allow the Zend application to perform the IO operations described above.  I also want these SELinux settings to persist after restarts.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to relabel the folder to be writable by httpd.

If http is the only thing (and say ftp or ssh) that will be writing to it then this should work.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/acme/myapp/files(/.*)?'
fixfiles restore /var/acme/myapp/files
```

Try writing into the folder then, it should work.

Comment: I tried the command you specified, but the targeted policy on my CenoOS host didn't have the httpd_sys_rw_content_t label, so I used the following commands instead: `/usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t '/var/acme/myapp/files(/.*)?'` and `/sbin/fixfiles restore /var/acme/myapp/files`.  So far, it appears to work.

Comment: I verified that it had the desired effect.  Thanks for the focused and correct answer.  I suspect different distros and versions come with different labels available.